# Error replacing values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the values in a column with numbers. These are the unique values in the column:

```
['R2' '01' '02' 'C1']
```

So I did this

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['rates'].apply({'R2': 1, '01' : 2, '02' : 3, 'C1' : 4}.get)
```

But when I try to print out df['rates'] after the supposed replacement, I still got same values:

```
['R2' '01' '02' 'C1']
```

This is how my file.csv looks like

```
amount,id,rates,height
1400,4,R2,3
1389,6,R2,8
10000,1,01,13
```

Comment: Can you provide code to produce your series?  That looks like it should work.

Comment: @piRSquared I have added it

Comment: You also need to show the contents of the file. Only first few lines.

Comment: I  have added it @piRSquared

Comment: Ohh. I think I know/crosses fingers. Apply doesn’t change the dataframe. You need to assign back to column

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I got it resolved. I needed to assign. See accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `map`:

```
df['rates'].map({'R2': 1, '01' : 2, '02' : 3, 'C1' : 4},inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
df['rates'] = df['rates'].map({'R2': 1, '01' : 2, '02' : 3, 'C1' : 4})
```

Actually your code works but need to assign:

```
df['rates']=df['rates'].apply({'R2': 1, '01' : 2, '02' : 3, 'C1' : 4}.get)
```

Comment: Its the same thing. It didn't work. 
df['rates'].map({'R2': 1, '01' : 2, '02' : 3, 'C1' : 4})
print df['rates']

Comment: @radioactive Edited mine

Comment: Oh thanks. It works, I needed to assign

Comment: @radioactive happy that i helped,